# Error when trying to run query using Access remote table

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, iis, odbc

I have an Access database with local and remote tables. The remote tables are linked to a Sql Server Database through an ODBC connection.

When I open the Access database, I can open and view the contents of both the local and remote tables. So this is proof that there should be no problem connecting to the remote tables from an ASP.NET app

Now when I run my ASP.NET app in Visual Studio, I am able to access both the local and remote tables in Access with no problem.

As soon as I put my app into IIS and run the app from localhost, I am only able to access the local tables in the Access file with my code but none of the remote tables! I get the following error when I try: "ODBC--connection to 'FMPOS_live' failed." But remember, I have no problem opening the remote tables from Access directly but I can't access them from my app running in IIS for some reason.

Is there a permission somewhere that depending on who or what is accessing the Access file, determines whether that process can use the remote tables??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the application pool identity. Access wasn't allowing access to it's remote tables by the default process ApplicationPoolIdentity Identity. I changed the identity to my windows user login and it worked!

Instructions:
1. Go to the Application Pool for your website
2. Click on it and select Advanced Settings
3. Under Process Model Identity, choose Custom Account and type your username and password for your windows login.

Answer (score 1):

When running from Visual Studio you are using your own credentials to connect to the SQL server.

When running from IIS you are using either ApplicationPoolIdentity, Network Service, or Local System depending on configuration of the application pool.  You would need to allow login and read privileges to whichever account the website is running under.

In the case of running from VS it's probably working because you're probably a sysadmin on the SQL server.

Try checking what user is running "w3wp.exe" in the task manager.

In the case of ApplicationPoolIdentity the username you're looking for will be IIS APPPOOL\NameOfApplicationPool.

Comment: I gave the user "Everyone", full access rights to the Access database and my web app still can't access the Access databases remote tables.Again it has no problem accessing the local tables. If this is a Sql Server problem, how does Sql Server even know what process is using the Access database to provide access to its tables?? I set up this situation on an entirely different web server, using a different Access database containing remote tables to another Sql Server database and the same thing happens,so it doesn't seem like this is some obscure problem limited to one computer.Any more ideas?

Comment: The tables are linked through the access db?  Man this sounds complicated!  Regardless I would imagine that the IIS process that opens the access database is still the process opening the SQL connection and therefor needs permissions.  I realize now my answer was unclear, you need to add the permissions to the SQL server database not the access database.

Comment: But I am using Sql Server Authentication with a username and password in ODBC to connect to Sql Server not windows authenticaton.

Comment: This is a pretty easy thing to reproduce. I'd be truly ecstatic if you were able to find a solution since I've spent hours on this. 1. Create a Sql Server database with one table. 2. Create an ODBC connection to this database. 3. Create an Access database with a local table. 4. Create a remote table also in this Access database using your ODBC connection to Sql Server. Now in ASP.NET try to access each of the tables in Access. You'll be able to read the local table but not the remote table.

Comment: When I view the web app in studio, where I can view the remote table, the connectionstring has to be Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\FMPOS\DataBase\Local\FMPOS_Main.mdb

When I publish it, it has to be Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\FMPOS\DataBase\Local\FMPOS_Main.mdb

Maybe the second connectionstring doesn't allow remote table viewing?

Comment: Well that certainly is another possibility.  To simplify things try altering the CS for the published site to say Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0  You may need the required components to be installed on the server as well.  If this doesn't work try adding ";User ID=<your username>;Password=<your password>" without the quotes to the end of the connection string.  That should tell us pretty quick if it works with proper credentials.  Of course you wouldn't likely want to leave it that way for security reasons.

Comment: I got it to run under Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 by going into IIS and and changing the App Pool to run 32bit applications. But now I still get the same other error now. The only thing left that I can think of that is different here is the IIS the app is running on. Maybe its a setting somewhere in IIS preventing remote table access in Access?? This is nuts!

Comment: Here is an update. My code could not access the remote tables in the built-in version of IIS that runs in the full version of Visual Studio. But I then downloaded IIS Express and then my code COULD access the remote tables! So this is definitely an IIS issue. Probably a bizarre security setting somewhere. Any additional help would be much appreciated.